# Sencha Extjs: Auto layout container does not take more width to accommodate vertical scrollbar. Is it a bug?

Tags: extjs

It looks like sencha extjs's auto layout container does not take up extra width for the vertical scrollbar unlike other layouts.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3glh&view/editor

Browse above fiddle, and you will notice that the auto container's vertical scrollbar appears over the textfield. The same problem does not happen for hbox/vbox. They take some extra width for the vertical scrollbar like any container with scrolling support should.

Is this a bug or one of the inherent limitations with sencha (for the auto layout). It seems unintuitive that a container with auto width wont take up more width for the vertical scrollbar. I am not looking for a workaround currently, but just trying to understand auto layout container correctly so that we can use it for what it can only provide.

Thank you

Comment: I guess its not a bug, have you tried to play around using: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.layout.container.Auto.html#cfg-reserveScrollbar property. Your fiddle does not contain the autoLayout.

Comment: I must have left out specifying layout config, in which case it will default auto layout anyway. I have explicitly specified layout: 'auto' now. Still no luck. I have tried specifying reserveScrollbar: true, but no luck (it does not appear to reserve additional space for vertical scrollbar). However, the fact that there is a config like reserveScrollbar present indicates this is not a bug but by design, which answers my question. You can specify your above comment in an answer, I'll mark it as a "correct answer".